# Is there a way to show more folders when bookmarking a page?

Tags: google-chrome

When adding a bookmark in Google Chrome, the eight most recently used folders are shown. I am constantly bookmarking things and usually use the same 10-15 folders.

Is there any way to increase the number of folders shown so that I'm not having to constantly click "Choose another folder" and browse for it?

Answer (score -2):

Since Google introduced the new bookmark manager, you can filter the list of folders. To do so, when adding a new bookmark (CTRL+D or clicking the star), choose 'Add to folder' by clicking on the little arrow on the right:

You can now filter the list of your folders. Keep in mind: The filtering unfortunately does **not** include subfolders (to this day). To find your folder quickly, without having to navigate first, you should keep all your folders on the top level.

The old bookmark manager can't do this and, since it's already been replaced, probably never will.

I tried including screenshots. I'm not allowed because of reputation < 10.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SuperUser. We try to get the most detailed answers available, so please elaborate on **how** to do what you mentioned in your answer.